# How to design a multi-client/server application?

Tags: java, sockets, client-server

In a socket-based application (client/server), I want to make the server perform as a proxy(manager) to handle several clients, and to get the message from one client and send it to the client, identified by an ID.

How can I know the required client running on different thread, how can I get the socket of the associate client that the id represents?

Comment: To whom vote to close the question, why you do that ?!!! If you have any problem with it , comment here !!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the messages to be delivered into a database, and make your threads check the database for new messages to be delivered to "their" clients on a regular basis.

If you do not want a dedicated database for the messages, build a flat file with simple ClientID->Socket mappings and use it like a "telephone book" kind of lookup system. Depending on the amount of clients you are planning to add, each thread could pre- and regularily reload such a file into it's memory for faster access...

Comment: How can I know the destination socket ?!

Comment: You don't really need to. The "sender" thread writes into the database with an ID that is known about the client, the "client" thread (which works independently) just checks for new messages for its client. Think of it as a kind of dead drop - one just puts stuff in, the other just puts stuff out...

Comment: If I don't want to use database ? I want to make it more real-time communication . is it possible ?

Comment: then skip the DB and just do a quick file-based lookup-table that has both the clients IDs and the appropriate socket. Think of it as a kind of "telephone book".

Comment: great, so I can associate the client ID with what ? how to store the socket? do you mean that I need to store the IP and the port and then the server(proxy/manager) will act as client and the receiver client with act as server ?

Comment: That's the general idea, yes.

Comment: I have changed the answer to reflect the lookup table idea.

Answer (score 3):

Just keep an in-memory hashmap of some sort of client-id to the java.net.Socket object that represents that client's socket. You need to come up with some way of assigning client IDs, either client supplied, or server-supplied through some authorization scheme.

When a message comes in for a client ID, grab the socket from the map and send it a message. This map needs to be stored in a singleton-type object, and needs to be properly synchronized. Use a concurrent hash map. Also, socket reads and writes would need to be synchronized if you're going multi-threaded.

I have posted some example code as a [github gist](https://gist.github.com/1177411). It's a bit different than I explained above. I don't store sockets in the map, I store client handlers which have the socket. Also, socket reads don't need synchronization: each clients has its own thread which is the only thread reading from the socket. Socket writes do need to be synchronized though, because the thread of the sending client is writing to the socket of the receiving client.

You're probably better off using something like [JBoss Netty](http://www.jboss.org/netty) rather than rolling your own though.

Comment: I don't understand the point of "Also, socket reads and writes would need to be synchronized if you're going multi-threaded." .. B.S. I need to make my own one because I want to understand the operations clearly as I want to implement someone using Android Java.

Comment: Sockets writes need to be synchronized. What if two messages come in for the same client? Depending on how you've set up your server, it could be possible that you'll send two messages simultaneously to the client. This could corrupt the data sent to the client. This is a fun question; I'll code up a small example of this and post it in a little bit.

Comment: Blurgh I am having trouble with posting code in a nice formatted way. Here's a link to the gist: https://gist.github.com/1177411

Comment: Ok, so that code is very simple. Just start up the server and start multiple telnets to localhost 8081. The first line you type in is the client ID. Any further lines you send are of the format "toclientid: message.".

Answer (score 1):

you can keep a lot of information about ID so each time it connects you get like the ip and save the thread it is running on and then you use like a hashmap to link the id to all that info then you can easily get the thread it is running on and send the information to the correct client